# Как записать результат запроса в переменную?

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть запрос, который возвращает количество записей, удовлетворяющих условию:

```
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
                $"SELECT COUNT(Id) AS count FROM DB WHERE Id={hash}",
                sqlConnection);
```

Соответственно, имеем одну колонку и одну строку. Как получить это значение и записать в переменную?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто:

```
int result = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```